# Please help me understand why variable variables isn't working for $_SESSION in php?

Tags: php, variables

I am trying to understand the double variables of php. Let's say I have this

```
$req = '_SESSION';
```

So, shouldn't `$$req` be equivalent to `$_SESSION`? But I am getting an error saying `undefined variable '_SESSION'`. Please explain this to me.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the **exact** code that you are trying to execute and the **exact** error message you are getting.  Cut & paste them; do not paraphrase.

Comment: The superglobals are aliases. They do not exist as references in the local scope, which the `${}` or `$$` local lookup requires.

Comment: By the way: Coding with variable names of variables is VERY bad style. We should really avoid this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that because (from [Variable Variables<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/language.variables.variable)):

> Please note that variable variables cannot be used with ***PHP's Superglobal arrays*** within functions or class methods.

Highlight is by me, [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/_SESSION) is such a *Superglobal array*.

Comment: I edited your answer, perhaps you find the one or other point nice for your other and future answers, too.

Comment: Also if you see the quote, it only says that it *cannot*, but it does not explain why. Compare with the comment by @mario below the question. That might be out of your scope, but I'd say his comment is worth to quote as well.

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION` is a superglobal variable but it isn't if you use `$$`.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, completely useless what you try. The concept you use here is made vor variable variable names, and not for fixed ones.

Just use a reference and that's it ...

```
$req = &$_SESSION;
```